# sql Query for max transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tables like this

[image]

I want to select Acct_id, number of transaction of user who have done  a maximum number of transaction.

`select Acct_id,max(num) From (select Acct_id, count(Acct_id) as num from Transactions group by Acct_id);`

My above sql query is giving me error-
**Every derived table must have its own alias**

> why my query was being fail without Alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query must be:-

```
SELECT Acct_id, MAX(num) 
FROM (SELECT Acct_id, COUNT(Acct_id) AS num 
      FROM Transactions 
      GROUP BY Acct_id) TAB;
```

Comment: why my query was being fail without Alias?

Comment: SQL identifies every dataset by name. So when you do a sub-select it temporarily creates a dataset without name. An dwhen you try to fetch the data from that dataset, it gives you an error for naming it. Once named everything sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the subselect an alias:

```
SELECT ...
 FROM (SELECT ...) AS anyAlias
 GROUP BY ...;
```

Comment: why my query was being fail without Alias?

Comment: Because the subselect "creates" a temporary table, that needs a name to be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

```
  select Acct_id,max(num) From (select Acct_id, count(Acct_id) as num 
  from Transactions group by Acct_id) as alias;
```

Another Solution:

```
select count(*) as total from transactions 
group by acct_id 
order by total desc limit 0,1
```

Comment: why my query was being fail without Alias?

Comment: you are creating another sort of virtual table using ( query ),,, sql needs to know the name of that temporary result set so you can name it anything...it could be even as myNewTable ..anything..

Answer (score 0):

Your subselect table needs an alias:

```
select 
    Acct_id,
    max(num) 
From (
    select 
        Acct_id, 
        count(Acct_id) as num 
    from Transactions 
    group by Acct_id
) as temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is right but problem to not speciry sub query table name likethis

```
select Acct_id,max(num) From (select Acct_id, count(Acct_id) as num from Transactions group by Acct_id) a;
```